# What indexes to create to speed up my heavy filter and grouping query?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a table like this, it has millions of records:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
`DateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`Col1` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Col2` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Col3` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Col4` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Event` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`State` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`DateTime`,`Col4`,`Event`,`State`)
);
```

I run a query to count the number of records, grouped by a time period, for a time range, if they match 'filters' based on the Col1/Col2/Col3/Col4 values. For example, a 3 minute period:

```
select
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(`DateTime`))-(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(`DateTime`)) % (3*60))) as 'Period',
    count(*) as 'NumberOfRecords'
from
    `myTable`
where
    `DateTime` > '2016-09-01' and `DateTime` < '2016-09-09'
    AND `Col1` IN (3, 6, 11, 14, etc... )
    AND `Col2` IN (5 ,25 , 325 , 293, 294, etc.... )
    AND `Col3` IN (3 , 9 , 95 , 395 , 435, etc...)
    AND `Col4` IN (124, 125, 135, 325, etc...)
group by
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`DateTime`) DIV (3*60);
```

What index should I have to speed up this query? I don't care how slow insertion gets, I want to have the query run extremely fast.

In general there are around 1,000 unique values for each col1,col2,col3,col4, but there are millions of records that would fit in the date range.

I was thinking something like:

```
CREATE INDEX `myIndex` ON `myTable` ( `DateTime`, `Col`,`Col2`,`Col3`,`Col4 )
```

But I am not sure I have the ordering right? Or is it better to make 4 indexes, one for each (`DateTime`,`ColX`)?

Comment: an index on (datetime,col1,col2,col3,col4). It is rather lean

Comment: create index \`idxBlah7\` on myTable(\`DateTime\`,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4)

Comment: drop index \`idxBlah7\` on myTable

Comment: Would I need an index for every possible combination of Col1 to Col4? For example if the query had no Col3, would I need: index (`DateTime`,Col1,col2,col4)?

Comment: It would use up to the *most* left-most and be useful up to that point. Then *where* from there. So a search for a certain query DateTime,col1,col2,col4,col6 would be useful up thru `col2`

Comment: The trick with composite indexes is to have them as useful as possible, with emphasis being on left-most, for the bulk of your query set. It is not uncommon to have a few of them with flipped ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is very hard to optimize given your five-column table structure, because you're running up to six different *range predicates*.

A range predicate includes operations `>`, `<`, `<>`, `BETWEEN`, `LIKE`, or `IN()`. Basically, any type of search other than `=`.

A range predicate potentially matches many values in the column.

An equality predicate matches exactly one value in the column (there may be many rows with that value, but it's one value).

When defining indexes, the columns you put in the index should be columns references in equality comparisons first, then just **one** column referenced in a range predicate. Any additional columns in the index beyond the first column referenced in a range predicate will not count for doing the lookup.

For example, if you have an index on `(col1, col2, col3)`, the following conditions:

```
WHERE col1=123 AND col2 IN (4, 5, 6) AND col3=789
```

This query can make use of the first two columns of the index. The `col3` will not use the index. The query will examine all rows matched by the first two terms, and evaluate the third term against all those rows one by one.

Whereas the same index will use all three columns for lookup by the following conditions:

```
WHERE col1=123 AND col2=789 AND col3 IN (4, 5, 6)
```

That is, equality predicates for the first two columns, and a range predicate for the last column in the index.

When you use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html), one of the columns reports the number of bytes of an index entry. In the above example, suppose all three columns are 32-bit integer columns. EXPLAIN for the first query will report that it uses 8 bytes (two integer's worth), and EXPLAIN for second query will report it uses 12 bytes (three integer's worth).

In your case, you have range predicates for *all* the terms in your conditions. This is not optimizable with a B-Tree index. It could use an index for any one of the columns. So you might create five individual indexes, each on one of the columns, and hope that the optimizer picks the one that narrows down the search most effectively. Or you can use [index hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) to pick the best index yourself.

I wrote a presentation you may find interesting called [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really)
. Here's a recording of my presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

There are other types of indexes besides B-tree indexes. A range predicate search over multiple columns may require an R-tree index. So you may find that to really optimize this query, you need to load a copy of the data into [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Crate](https://crate.io/) or some other search engine like that.

Comment: Excellent answer bill.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed index might be the best that you can do.  All your comparisons are inequalities, so only the first key in the index can be used to satisfy the `where` clause.  And, the date is probably the most selective (or consistently selective) of the columns.

Including the other columns is helpful.

As for sorting the `IN` lists, that is unnecessary:  MySQL does it for you.  Better than that, MySQL creates a binary tree structure so searching is even more efficient.  (Note that in other databases you would want to sort the values by *frequency*, not by *value*, because the list would be processed in order.)

There is no way to use an index for the aggregation, unfortunately.  So, you are probably stuck with the performance of the query you have, unless you can figure out how to change the conditions to strict equality conditions connected by `AND`.

Comment: What do you mean by strict equality conditions? Isn't 'in' just expanded to OR logic?

Comment: @SectoKia . . . I clarified what I meant by that.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way.

You apparently have many rows for each combination, since you are fetching `COUNT(*)`, correct?

Do you only want 3-minute intervals?  Let's say 'yes'.  Then let's build this "Summary table":

```
CREATE TABLE Summary1234 (
`Period` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`Col1` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Col2` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Col3` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Col4` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
NumberOfRecords SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`DateTime`,col1, col2, col3, col4)
);
```

Then effectively (and incrementally) do

```
INSERT INTO Summary 1234
    SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(`DateTime`)) -
                         (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(`DateTime`)) % (3*60))) as 'Period',
            col1, col2, col3, col4,
            count(*) as 'NumberOfRecords'
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5;
```

I say "incrementally" because you should update this table every 3 minutes with all the new rows.

Then do your query from this table:

```
select  Period,
        SUM(NumberOfRecords) AS NumberOfRecords
    from  `myTable`
    where  `Period` >= '2016-09-01'  -- note: I fixed your inequality
      and  `Period`  < '2016-09-09'
      AND  `Col1` IN (3, 6, 11, 14, etc... )
      AND  `Col2` IN (5 ,25 , 325 , 293, 294, etc.... )
      AND  `Col3` IN (3 , 9 , 95 , 395 , 435, etc...)
      AND  `Col4` IN (124, 125, 135, 325, etc...)
    GROUP BY  Period;
```

[*More on summary tables*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-warehousing-summary-tables/)

If the counts are typically 10, this summarization will be noticeably better.
If they are rarely more than 1, this will not be very useful.  (Hence, I said "may be better".)

If you want 6-minute intervals, or 1-hour intervals, etc, you can do a slightly different `SELECT` to achieve such from that one Summary table.  Do not make multiple summary tables for only that difference.